# Find Treeview node recursively

Tags: c#

I have the following tree

```
A
+-B
+-C 
| +-D
+-E
  +-F
  +-G
```

I am trying to find `G` given `A`

```
private TreeListNode FindTreeNode(TreeListNode node, Enumerations.ItemType type,
                                  Nullable<long> id)
{
    TreeListNode found = null;
    foreach (TreeListNode child in node.Nodes)
    {
        if ((Enumerations.ItemType)child[2] == type)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                found = child;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((long)child[0] == (long)id)
                {
                    found = child;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                found = FindTreeNode(child, type, id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

```
FindTreeNode(root,C,null)
```

Since `C` comes before `G` the routinue works for finding `C` and its children. 
if the else block `if(child.HasChildren)` it finds `C` and its children. 
When I am trying to find `E` and its children, 
the recursive call isn't working correctly. 
It comes in with the root node `A` but after it enters the recursion child becomes `C` and then `nodes.Nodes = 1`

When I searching for `F` or `G` it has to continue its recursion. So how do I set the child to be the root node

Comment: possible duplicate of [TreeView search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530643/treeview-search)

Comment: What does your `TreeListNode` look like? And why are you passing `C` as your second argument to `FindTreeNode`? From the signature it should be a `Enumerations.ItemType`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You break even if the recursive call hasn't found anything. Change the relevant code to:

```
if (child.HasChildren)
{
    found = FindTreeNode(child, type, id);
    if (found != null) 
        break;
}
```

---

Your method looks really complicated. Wouldn't this just do the same?

```
private TreeListNode FindTreeNode(TreeListNode node, Enumerations.ItemType type,
                                  Nullable<long> id)
{
    foreach (TreeListNode child in node.Nodes) {
        if ((Enumerations.ItemType)child[2] == type &&
            (id == null || (long)child[0] == id.Value)) {

            return child;
        }

        if (child.HasChildren) {
            TreeListNode found = FindTreeNode(child, type, id);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```