# Search items in a treeview C#

Tags: c#, search, treeview

I was looking for a way to search for an item in a treeview in C#. I used the following question/answer [TreeView search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530643/treeview-search) and it works great. The only issue I'm having now is that I can only look through nodes that have been expanded at least once. So I added a ExpandAll() and Collapse() to the Load event of my form so that I can find any item anywhere in the tree.
But now, I'm dealing with very big hierarchies and it takes 45+ seconds to load my dialog box because of that expandAll() call. Is there a way to do that search without calling expandAll() first?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Separate the model from the view.

Comment: Are you planning to show the item found placing it on the tree view or just show the single item like a search result?

Comment: Yes, I need to show the item(s) found in the tree. The search button selects the next item that matches the searched string. I think I need to perform the search in the data I use to build the tree instead of searching in the tree. Is that what you suggest @HansPassant?